# Time dilation apeears in the both frame: Where is the problem?

Tags: special-relativity

Let we consider  time in  stationary frmae t, and respect the to stationary frame moving frame time $t^ \prime $ .

According to lorentz transformation,

$$t^\prime= \frac{t-\frac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ and according to inverse Lorentz transformation, $$t= \frac{t^\prime +\frac{vx^\prime}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

If we measure a event we have got,$$ t= t_2 -t_1$$
then, $$t= \frac{t_2^ \prime  -t_2^ \prime }{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
 $$t= \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Therefore t is greather than $t_0$.

But if we calculate the time dilation in otherway, we have got, 
$$t_0 = t_2^\prime -t_1^\prime $$

then, $$t_0= \frac{t_2  -t_2 }{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
 $$t_0= \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
Therefore $t_0$ is greather than $t$.

I think I am doing wrong somewhere, because I have proven the stationary time longer and after some time I got the opposite. Can you please tell me that where did I get wrong?

Comment: In your second equation, it is a $x'$ and not a $x$.

Comment: It is not only a correction. Difference of times at constant $x$ and difference of times at constant $x'$ are completely different...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time Dilation - How does it know which Frame of Reference to age slower?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6147/time-dilation-how-does-it-know-which-frame-of-reference-to-age-slower)

Comment: Each inertial frame is equivalent. Hence, both of them can assume that the other person's clock is running slow and there is no experiment in this universe that would let them tell actually whose clock is running slow. So the question of comparison is sort of meaningless. You haven't fully understood the first postulate of theory of special relativity then. Each person will say my clock is running faster and hence the results that you obtain that shows this very fact w.r.t. two different inertial observers.

Comment: Also if you consider the twin paradox, you cannot tell which twin is younger until one of them accelerates to come back. You have to come out of all the prejudices and start looking at things from a completely neutral and scientific point of view to fully appreciate this. To say the one who is travelling actually is younger comes out the prejudices you have, but experimentally you can never tell who is younger and if he never returns back to earth. There is no way of knowing who is younger and each one of them will see that the other one lived longer. Quite Shocking, but true.

Answer (score 1):

For defining time dilation you first need to understand 'proper time interval'.
Proper time(denoted $\Delta t_0$) is time taken in an inertial frame in which two events occur at same position. This proper time interval is dilated in all other frames of reference.

Let two events occur at $(x_1,t_1)$ & $(x_2,t_2)$ in $S$ frame and they occur at $(x'_1,t'_1)$ & $(x'_2,t'_2)$ in $S'$ frame.

The Lorentz transforms for $x$ & $t$ can be written as

$x'=\gamma(x-vt)\\
t'=\gamma(t-\dfrac{vx}{c^2})$

If $x_1=x_2$,

then using Lorentz transforms one can write,

$t'_2-t'_1=\Delta t'=\gamma(\Delta t)$

Which means the time interval will appear to be dilated in $S'$ frame.

Where as if you use inverse Lorentz transforms to go from $S'$ to $S$ then,

Notice $x'_2 \neq x'_1$

Therefore,

$\Delta t=t_2-t_1 \neq \gamma \Delta t'$  because time interval $\Delta t'$ is not proper.

In this answer I have used $\gamma=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Comment: user40330: "_[...] need to understand 'proper time interval'._" -- It's surely important to understand **and to distinguish** several related notions: **(1)** the duration of any particular participant $A$ between two particular of his indications (e.g. from indication $A_J$ of being met/passed by participant $J$ until indication $A_K$ of being met/passed by participant $K$); symbolically $\tau A[ \circ_J, \circ_K ]$; **(2)** the interval (magnitude) of any two timelike events; such as $s[ \mathcal E_{AK}, \mathcal E_{AJ} ]$, and finally **(3)** anything having to do with coordinates $t$.